# Creating routes with passing parametr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes, rails-routing

I need to create a rout, which url will look like this: www.sitename.com/action_name/[:id]
Write it as follows:

```
get '/how-to-transfer-colleges/:id', to:'seo_pages#how_to_transfer_colleges'
get '/how-to-transfer-colleges', to: 'seo_pages#how_to_transfer_colleges'
```

But I know that it should be written by scope and I write it by guide:

```
scope module :users do 
  resources :how_to_transfer_colleges
end
```

This does not work and I understand that the scope was written incorrectly. I would be grateful for any help in correctly creating this rout using scope

Answer (score 0):

Check the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

```
scope module: :users do # note the ":" after "module"
  ....
end
```

Note that you won't have the same paths using that scope. You'll have something like `/users/how-to-transfer-colleges` on the url and it will point to the UsersController.

I'm don't think it "should" be written with a scope, you can just leave it as it is now, I don't see the benefit, I think you are overthinking it. Routes helpers are there to help, you are free to not use them if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who drew attention to this question. Here is the solution I came to and that I was looking for:

```
scope:'how-to-transfer-colleges', as: :how_to_transfer_colleges do
  get '/:id', to: 'seo_pages#how_to_transfer_colleges'
  get '/', to: 'seo_pages#how_to_transfer_colleges'
end
```

Hope that would be helpful for somebody